# Enabling PROGUARD - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In the release mode, when i enable **only multi dex**, my app size is 33.30MB which is quite large. After series of research, i realized PROGUARD shrinks the apk size. 
Enabling proguard in my solution, i get this error. What could i be missing in my solution for PROGUARD to work (shrink my app size)?

```
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNativeListener
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find superclass or interface com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative$NativeAdListener
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx$zza: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdErrorType
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNativeAsset
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNativeListener
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdErrorType
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNativeAsset
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.n$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdErrorType
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative$NativeAdListener
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.sdk.InMobiSdk
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.sdk.InMobiSdk
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiAdRequestStatus
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative$NativeAdListener
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiAdRequestStatus
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiAdRequestStatus
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.adapters.q$1: can't find referenced class com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative
PROGUARD : warning : com.facebook.ads.internal.view.d.c.a: can't find referenced method 'DefaultTrackSelector(android.os.Handler,com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection$Factory)' in program class com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaa: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzad: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzad: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzu: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx$zza
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx$zza: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx$zza
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateParseException
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
PROGUARD : warning : gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen: can't find referenced field 'int splash_wrapper_rl' in program class gr.net.maroulis.library.R$id
PROGUARD : warning : gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen: can't find referenced field 'int logo' in program class gr.net.maroulis.library.R$id
PROGUARD : warning : gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen: can't find referenced field 'int header_tv' in program class gr.net.maroulis.library.R$id
PROGUARD : warning : gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen: can't find referenced field 'int footer_tv' in program class gr.net.maroulis.library.R$id
PROGUARD : warning : gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen: can't find referenced field 'int before_logo_tv' in program class gr.net.maroulis.library.R$id
PROGUARD : warning : gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen: can't find referenced field 'int after_logo_tv' in program class gr.net.maroulis.library.R$id
PROGUARD : warning : okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
PROGUARD : warning : okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
PROGUARD : warning : there were 156 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

**proguard.cfg**

```
Environment Variables passed to tool:
      PROGUARD_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mandroid/proguard
    /usr/bin/java -jar /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mandroid/proguard/lib/proguard.jar -include /Users/emmnock/AndroidStudioProjects/android-sdk-macosx//tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt -include obj/Release/proguard/proguard_xamarin.cfg -include obj/Release/proguard/proguard_project_references.cfg -include obj/Release/proguard/proguard_project_primary.cfg -include proguard.cfg -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/00d975c90.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/0757626b0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/1db418320.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/1f4fd9cc0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/211c61910.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/2f4d086a0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/581878c90.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/67b1d0a90.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/8f1de9cb0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/a35ed7280.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/acdd43380.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/b76e0d310.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/c756521f0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/d87effcf0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/d99a9fda0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/d9f2c52f0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/dc663e480.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/e5bf18810.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/e843ef2a0.txt -include obj/Release/XbdMerge/proguard/fb4df8d50.txt "-injars 'obj/Release/proguard/__proguard_input__.jar':'/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v7.1/mono.android.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Bolts.AppLinks/library_project_imports/bin/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Bolts.Tasks/library_project_imports/bolts-tasks.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/EasySplashScreen/library_project_imports/bin/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/ExoPlayer/library_project_imports/bin/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/FormsViewGroup/library_project_imports/formsviewgroup.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Glide/library_project_imports/glide-3.8.0.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView/library_project_imports/bin/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Square.OkHttp/library_project_imports/okhttp.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Square.OkIO/library_project_imports/okio.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Square.Picasso/library_project_imports/picasso-2.5.2.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Facebook/library_project_imports/bin/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork/library_project_imports/bin/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics.Impl/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Common/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Database/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Database.Connection/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Iid/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Storage/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.Firebase.Storage.Common/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Clearcut/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gass/library_project_imports/classes.jar':'obj/Release/__library_projects__/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks/library_project_imports/classes.jar'" "-libraryjars '/Users/emmnock/AndroidStudioProjects/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-25/android.jar'" -outjars "obj/Release/proguard/__proguard_output__.jar" -optimizations !code/allocation/variable 
    proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '-dontwarn' in line 1 of file 'proguard.cfg',
      included from argument number 10
        at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(Unknown Source)
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1922,3): error MSB6006: "java" exited with code 1.
  Done executing task "Proguard" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Please upload a full diagnostic build output.https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: @JonDouglas https://gist.github.com/anonymous/91176f39efaf73c7322f21d20547ffff

Comment: It looks like you might just need to add some exceptions to your proguard.cfg file here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393942/proguard-java-exe-exited-with-code-1-after-adding-modernhttpclient/43555029#43555029

Answer (score 2):

Proguard is telling you that you need to fix your warnings before it will allow it to build.

```
   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
        at proguard.Initializer.execute(Unknown Source)
        at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(Unknown Source)
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(Unknown Source)
```

You can either go one-by-one to fix all of these errors(By using `-keep`), or you can ignore the warnings. There are two ways to go about this:

1. Using `-ignorewarnings`

Specifies to print any warnings about unresolved references and other important problems, but to continue processing in any case. Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. For instance, if the unresolved classes or class members are indeed required for processing, the processed code will not function properly. Only use this option if you know what you're doing!

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#ignorewarnings

2. Using `-dontwarn [class_filter]`

Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important problems at all. The optional filter is a regular expression; ProGuard doesn't print warnings about classes with matching names. Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. For instance, if the unresolved classes or class members are indeed required for processing, the processed code will not function properly. Only use this option if you know what you're doing!

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#dontwarn

You can find out how to create a custom proguard configuration via the documentation I wrote:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/proguard/#Customizing_ProGuard

Why do you get those warnings you may ask? It's most likely due to the Linker stripping these items before Proguard is run. See my notes on this here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/proguard/#Linker_Step

Comment: So i could basically create a  `custom proguard configuration` to solve this ?

Comment: Try it out. Initially you can start with `-ignorewarnings` and see if that lets your build work.  Then you can work on figuring out the rest :)

Comment: please look at the error i am getting using - ignorewarings

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743557/xamarin-proguard-parseexception-unknown-option-in-line-1-of-file-properties